# linq to sql row number per group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with a job description column and date column. I would like to get the row number for each row after grouping by description as shown below.

```
 Description                     RunDate                    rn

File Cleanup             2013-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 1
File Cleanup             2013-12-29 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 2
Billing Extract          2013-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 1
Billing Extract          2013-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 2
Billing Extract          2013-12-29 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 3
Unit Data Extract   2013-12-05 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  1
Monthly Extract         2013-12-05 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  1
```

I was able to achieve this in SQL with the following query

```
SELECT [Description], RunDate, rn = ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY [Description] ORDER BY RunDate DESC)
FROM BackgroundJobs
```

I am not able to convert this into Linq to SQL. I tried using

```
var jobGroups = context.BackgroundJobs.GroupBy(g => new{g.Description, g.RunDate}).Select((jobs, index) => new { RowCount = index++, BackgroundJob = jobs }).Tolist();
```

The output was

```
 Description                     RunDate                   rn

File Cleanup            2013-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  1
File Cleanup            2013-12-29 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2
Billing Extract         2013-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  3
Billing Extract         2013-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  4
Billing Extract         2013-12-29 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  5
Unit Data Extract   2013-12-05 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  6
Monthly Extract         2013-12-05 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  7
```

The Linq to SQL query incremented the row number but it did not reset to 1 when the description changed.

Please advise how to reset the row number to 1 when the group description changes in linq to SQL.

Thank you
Mahita

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, but you must do the `Select` with index one level deeper:

```
var jobGroups = 
    context.BackgroundJobs
           .GroupBy(job => new { job.Description, job.RunDate })
           .Select(g => new
            {
               g.Key, 
               Jobs = g.Select((job,i) => new
               { 
                  RowCount = i + 1,
                  job
               })
            })
           .Tolist();
```

You may need an `AsEnumerable()` before `Select(g => ...` because in many implementations of LINQ to a SQL backend the indexed overload of `Select` isn't supported.

Comment: Just an FYI, the `g.Select(...)` will error because it can't assign a name so you would have to actually give the anonymous type a name for that

Comment: @JoePhilllips Thanks. Made me aware of another oversight.

Comment: Also, I don't think you have to do `i+1`, you can just do `i` I bet

Comment: @JoePhilllips Maybe. I'll leave it. It's of minor importance.